# Pragmatically disable payment method if not in specific zone opencart

Tags: php, opencart, payment-gateway, opencart2.x

How would i disable 'Cash On Delivery' payment method in opencart 2.x checkout if the selected address is from a zone_id that i don't want

I don't know the specific variable to do the logic; I have tried adding the logic below but it does not work

```
    if (($this->config->get('cod_geo_zone_id')) == 1736) {
        $status = true;    
    } else {
    $status = false;
    }
```

The complete code is as below in: **catalog\model\payment\cod.php**

```
<?php
class ModelPaymentCOD extends Model {
    public function getMethod($address, $total) {
        $this->load->language('payment/cod');

         $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "zone_to_geo_zone WHERE geo_zone_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('cod_geo_zone_id') . "' AND country_id = '" . (int)$address['country_id'] . "' AND (zone_id = '" . (int)$address['zone_id'] . "' OR zone_id = '0')"); 





        if ($this->config->get('cod_total') > 0 && $this->config->get('cod_total') > $total) {
            $status = false;
        } elseif (!$this->config->get('cod_geo_zone_id')) {
            $status = true;
        } elseif ($query->num_rows) {
            $status = true;
        } 
        else {
            $status = false;
        }

        if (($this->config->get('cod_geo_zone_id')) == 1736) {
            $status = true; 
        } else {
        $status = false;
        }


        /*$zonex = $address['zone_id'];
        if  ($zonex == 1736) { 
            $status = false;

        }*/


        $method_data = array();

        if ($status) {
            $method_data = array(
                'code'       => 'cod',
                'title'      => $this->language->get('text_title'),
                'terms'      => '',
                'sort_order' => $this->config->get('cod_sort_order')
            );
        }


         return $method_data;
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I guess that you would need to make $status false if you want it disabled. And there you have unneeded extra parentheses, try something like: `if ($this->config->get('cod_geo_zone_id') == 1736) {
            $status = false; 
        }`

Comment: @qdev hi, i have tried         `if (($this->config->get('cod_geo_zone_id')) == 1736) {
        $status = false;    
        } else {
  $status = true;
  }` But still does not work. i think i am not catching the right variable

Comment: No, you shouldn't return true on else !
I don't know what your query returns, but I suspect that you need to compare something like this: `if ($query->row['geo_zone_id'] == 1736) {
            $status = false; 
        }`

Comment: but depends if that query will always return only one row or multiple, you should debug with var_dump($query) to see what's containing ;)

Comment: do you want to Disable Cash On Delivery for selected address whose zone_id = $this->config->get('cod_geo_zone_id') i.e. 1736 in your case?

Comment: @RahulVerma yes, i have managed to find the zone_id variable `if ($this->session->data['shipping_address']['zone_id'] !== '1736') {
   
   $status = false;
  }`